# JS sort an Array from its children's inner HTML values?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, scope

Is there a way to sort a JS array based upon the values of its html element's innerText?
I am creating creating a div element (class="inbox" id="inbox${var}") with a number as its innerText, I am then pushing all divs into an array (numArr). I would like to sort those divs into a descending order based on their inner numerical value.

**JavaScript**

```
const addBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');
console.log(addBtn);

const addIpt = document.getElementById('add-ipt');
console.log(addIpt);

const box = document.getElementById('box');
console.log(box);

const sortBtn = document.getElementById('sort-btn');
console.log(sortBtn);

let numArr = [];

let numInc = 0;

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(addIpt.value);
  let boxNum = addIpt.value;
  console.log(boxNum);
  console.log(box);
  box.innerHTML += `<div class="inbox" id="inbox${numInc}">${boxNum}</div>`;
  boxNum = 0;
  empty();
  addToArr();
  numInc++;
  console.log(numInc);
});

//Updated Function
function addToArr() {
  numArr = box.children;
  console.log(numArr);
}

function empty() {
  document.getElementById('add-ipt').value = '';
}

//New Function Below

function parseAndOrder() {
  numArr.sort(parseInt(el1.innerText), parseInt(el2.innerText));
  return parseInt(el2.innerText) - parseInt(el1.innerText);
}

//New SortButton
sortBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  parseAndOrder();
});
```

**New HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Stackoverflow Questions</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, iniatal-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stackoverflow.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="add-ipt" type="number">
        <button id="add-btn">Add</button>
        <button id="sort-btn">Sort</button>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="stackoverflow.js"></script>

</HTML>
```

Comment: The comparison function should use `parseInt(el1.innerText)` and `parseInt(el2.innerText)` to compare the two elements.

Comment: BTW, `numArr` will be a 2-dimensional array. Each element is a list of children.

Comment: Could You expand on this a bit? I updated my code to include what I thought you were recommending, Its not working though, so I don't think I'm understanding it thoroughly.

Comment: The argument to `sort()` must be a function that performs the comparison.

Comment: You still don't seem to be adding to `numArr` correctly in the first place. `addToArr()`. You call that after adding one row to the box. But it adds all the children to the array every time, not just the row you added. So you end up with a 2-dimensional array like this: `[[row1], [row1, row2], [row1, row2, row3], ...]`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm going for, but I do get what your saying now; so I'm gonna work on that. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to push onto the array, just do `numArr = box.children()`

Comment: Okay I'm going to update the post real quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep pushing input number in the array as user is adding. Then sort the array and populate the html using it.

Haven't tested this but something like this should work

```
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
const addIpt = document.getElementById("add-ipt");
const box = document.getElementById("box");

let numArr = [];

addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  numArr.push(addIpt.value);

  // sort array
  numArr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});

  empty();
  printElements();
});

function empty() {
  addIpt.value = "";
};

function printElements() {
  let content = '';
  numArr.forEach((num, index) => {
    content += `<div class="inbox" id="inbox${index}">${num}</div>`;
  });
  box.innerHTML = content;
};
```

Comment: Sidenote, you should add some validation check to see if user is entering number only

Comment: Yes, this works, but I'm really trying to sort the divs themselves, as opposed to reinserting them into the DOM after ordering; because I plan on storing information within the divs down the road. Thank you though.